# Counting total number of tasks executed in a multiprocessing.Pool during execution

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'd love to give an indication of the current talk in total that we are only. I'm farming work out and would like to know current progress. So if I sent `100` jobs to `10` processors, how can I show what the current number of jobs that have returned is. I can get the id's but but how do I count up the number of completed returned jobs from my map function.

I'm calling my function as the following:

```
op_list = pool.map(PPMDR_star, list(varg))
```

And in my function I can print the current name

```
current = multiprocessing.current_process()
print 'Running: ', current.name, current._identity
```

Comment: You want to be able to check this from within each worker process?

Comment: @dano - I don't mind - just something as the processes are being executed. Pool.map doesn't return until complete so by then its too late for any stats - or is there a way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use `pool.map_async` you can pull this information out of the [`MapResult`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) instance that gets returned. For example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    return i


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool.map_async(worker, range(15))
    while not result.ready():
        print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
        time.sleep(1)
    real_result = result.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output:

```
num left: 15
num left: 14
num left: 13
num left: 12
num left: 11
num left: 10
num left: 9
num left: 9
num left: 8
num left: 8
num left: 7
num left: 7
num left: 6
num left: 6
num left: 6
num left: 5
num left: 5
num left: 5
num left: 4
num left: 4
num left: 4
num left: 3
num left: 3
num left: 3
num left: 2
num left: 2
num left: 2
num left: 2
num left: 1
num left: 1
num left: 1
num left: 1
```

`multiprocessing` internally breaks the iterable you pass to `map` into chunks, and passes each chunk to the children processes. So, the `_number_left` attribute really keeps track of the number of *chunks* remaining, not the individual elements in the iterable. Keep that in mind if you see odd looking numbers when you use large iterables. It uses chunking to improve IPC performance, but if seeing an accurate tally of completed results is more important to you than the added performance, you can use the `chunksize=1` keyword argumment to `map_async` to make `_num_left` more accurate. (The `chunksize` usually only makes a noticable performance difference for very large iterables. Try it for yourself to see if it really matters with your usecase).

As you mentioned in the comments, because `pool.map` is blocking, you can't really get this unless you were to start a background thread that did the polling while the main thread blocked in the `map` call, but I'm not sure there's any benefit to doing that over the above approach.

The other thing to keep in mind is that you're using an internal attribute of `MapResult`, so it's possible that this could break in future versions of Python.

Comment: Thanks. I tried just running with map_async, but got an issue with: 'MapResult' object is not iterable

Comment: @Navonod I've updated my answer. You need to call `result.get()` on the `MapResult` instance to get the actual list of results.

Comment: I noticed one issue with what seems to be a lot of jobs to map over - in that my numbers are incorrect. I sent 8k jobs over - yeah a lot of file, but I get weird reporting. I.e: Found # files  8067
Number of files left to process: 253

Comment: @Navonod see the paragraph immediately after the example output. You see that because of the chunking that `multiprocessing` does internally. Use `map_async(func, iterable, chunksize=1)` and you should see the number you expect.

Comment: sorry was hiding there. Works fine now! Thanks!

Comment: To get number of tasks left (not chunks) one can do: `result._value.count(None)` in place of `result._number_left`