# multiprocessing.pool.MapResult._number_left not giving result I would expect

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am confused as to what `_number_left` is supposed to return.  I assumed it was the number tasks remaining in the pool, but it does not appear to provide the correct value in my code.  For example, if I have a pool of 10 workers counting to the number 1000, I would expect `result._number_left` to countdown from 1000.  However, it only tells me I have 40 left until the code is about finished.  Am I missing something here?

Code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def do_something(x):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)
    return


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)

    result = pool.map_async(do_something, [x for x in range(1000)])
    while not result.ready():
        print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
        result.wait(timeout=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Considering that it's an undocumented private attribute that's changed at least once between 2.6 and 3.6, why would you expect it to have _any_ particular meaning except the meaning you could glean from reading the source code for some particular version?

Answer (score 2):

First, `_number_left` is an undocumented private attribute of an undocumented class. There's no reason you should expect it to have *any* particular meaning.

If you look at [the source for the undocumented `MapResult`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L661) class, you can see how it's used in CPython 3.6 in particular.

First, it gets initialized:

```
self._number_left = length//chunksize + bool(length % chunksize)
```

So, already, it's pretty clear that it's never going to be the length of your iterable; it's going to be the expected number of chunks needed to map the whole iterable. Then, it counts down from there whenever `_set` is called, which… well, that's pretty complicated, but it's clearly not once per value.

At any rate, whatever you're trying to do, there probably is a way to actually do it, without peeking at private attributes and guessing at what they might mean. For example, if you just want to get some progress, but can't use `imap_unordered` because you need the results in an ordered list at the end, it's pretty easy to build an ordered list out of it: just pass `enumerate(iterable)` in, modify or wrap `func` to return the index along with the value, and then sort the results that come back.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to add `chunksize=1` to my `map_async` call.  Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239072/594371).

New Code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def do_something(x):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)
    return


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)

    result = pool.map_async(do_something, [x for x in range(1000)], chunksize=1)
    while not result.ready():
        print("num left: {}".format(result._number_left))
        result.wait(timeout=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```